# Junit: Assert.assertNotSame returning true despite the fact the two strings are equal

Tags: java, junit, assertions

I'm using JUnit 4.12 and PowerMock 1.6.2.  I have the following code:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
...
System.out.println("equals?" + obj.equals(myObj.getUser().getUserName()));
Assert.assertNotSame(obj.getUserName(), myObj.getUser().getUserName());
```

The system out call prints `equals? true`, however the following assert line succeeds, where I expect it to fail if the strings are equal.  Why isn't `assertNotSame` not working and what is the proper method I should be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`assertNotSame(a, b)` checks that `a != b`, i.e. that a and b are not references to the exact same object. That's very different from testing that `a.equals(b)` is false, which chacks that the two string don't have the same characters.

You should use

```
assertFalse(obj.getUserName().equals(myObj.getUser().getUserName()))
```

I would recommend using [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/index.html), which has dozens of much more expressive assertions:

```
assertThat(myObj.getUser().getUserName()).isNotEqualTo(obj.getUserName());
```